# Receive UDP string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sockets, udp

I'm trying to read data by UDP protocol when press a button, but I can only read the data once after pressing a button. I need to receive this
string of data continuously and insert a LF after CR to fix my string to send another software. Can you help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(6009);
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            label2.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            button1.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            
            
            

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
E.g string 

$GPGGA,010147,2258.41941,S,04200.77435,W,2,07,1.4,0.0,M,0.0,M,2.2,0362*56
```

Comment: Hi. Just a general question - do you have to use UDP? It's not guaranteed so you may well find yourself "debugging" when the real is issue is the OS has just decided to drop some data on the floor. If you need to be sure your data is arriving correctly and you need to know if it's failed then use TCP. (Better still use an HTTP server if you can. Writing your own comms layer is best avoided if possible.)

Comment: "I need to receive this string of data continuously" sounds like you need a `while` lopp somewhere, but you probably need `async` otherwise you will lock up. "insert a LF after CR to fix my string to send another software" are you sending or receiving? Your code only has receive